# C# reads the value of the cell formula in the CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I have a CSV file as shown below. I am in the TXT way to read, but in some cells I encountered a problem, I read the formula, rather than the formula calculated after the value, I would like to ask what framework or method can help me?

[image]

Comment: Please be carefull when selecting tags for your questions, so you don't select the C language tag instead of the C#.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre].

Comment: My English is not proficient, I want to raise the question politely, if accidentally offended you, I am sorry

Comment: You didn't offend him, he's just trying to help, btw if you're interested in some easy libraries to work with you can try with [csvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/), this is a reliable and easy library to read and write csv files

Comment: 1) Open your CSV file in Excel. 2) Copy the range you want. 3) Open a new workbook. 4) Paste special -> Values. 5) Save the new workbook as a CSV file. 6) If that's too manual, save the file in .xlxs format and search for Excel interop to learn how to work with a spreadsheet (as opposed to a CSV file) using C#. If you want to evaluate the results of formulae in spreadsheets then it's best to get Excel to do it for you.

Comment: @sbridwell First of all, I appreciate your advice, but I have a lot of CSV files and they are growing. If I used every file this way, I felt it might be a bit slow. Thank you again for your advice